# Matrix calculation for different levels of factor variable wih elements from another list (but with same levels as the matrix) acting on each level

Tags: r, matrix, lapply

I have the following simplified problem:

```
temp <- matrix(rnorm(1200), ncol = 4)
lev <- as.factor(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 100))
dfr <- data.frame(lev = lev, temp = temp)
lv <- lapply(split(dfr, dfr$lev), function(x) var(x[,-1]))

y <- matrix(rnorm(1200), ncol = 4)
```

Let us say that the rows of y also are assigned the same levels as lev. So, for each lev, I would like to matrix multiply the inverse of the variance matrix associated with that level.

To recap, for all the y-rows corresponding to the level "a", I would like to post-multiply with lv$a, for all the y-rows corresponding to the level "b", I would like to post-multiply with lv$b and  for all the y-rows corresponding to the level "c", I would like to post-multiply with lv$c.

Following this transformation, I would like to end up with a dataframe or a matrix with rows given by these lev-transformed rows of y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temp <- matrix(rnorm(1200), ncol = 4)
lev <- as.factor(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 100))
dfr <- data.frame(lev = lev, temp = temp)
lv <- lapply(split(dfr, dfr$lev), function(x) var(x[,-1]))

y <- matrix(rnorm(1200), ncol = 4)


dd <- data.frame(levs = lev, y = y)
levs.mat <- lapply(split(dd, dd$levs), function(x)(x))
tmp <- mapply(FUN = function(x, lev)(as.matrix(x[, -1])%*%solve(lev)), x = levs.mat, lev = lv)
```

At this point, I get a matrix of dimension 300 x 4. but the three columns are not quite correct. I can change this to an array:

```
dim(tmp) <- c(100, ncol(y), nlevels(lev))
X <- aperm(tmp, c(1, 3, 2))
dim(X) <- dim(y)
```

Check for correctness:compare

```
head(X)
```

with

```
y[1:6, ] %*% solve(as.matrix(lv$a))
```

etc and both yield the same results.

yielding X.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
out <- lapply(split(seq_along(lev), lev),
              function(i) y[i, ] %*% solve(var(temp[i, ])))
```

now `out` is a list of three 100 × 40 matrices

```
> lapply(out, dim)
$a
[1] 100   4

$b
[1] 100   4

$c
[1] 100   4
```

which can be stacked with `do.call(rbind, out)` if necessary.

**Attention:** Notice that the result does not match the matrix `X` from your answer. I'm not sure what your change of dimensions at the end does.

Comment: Changed code to diagnose for correctness. Your answer is also correct and FWIW, shorter. Not sure which one is more preferred.